Does this matrix look like a matrix to you? It doesn't to me
$$\begin{pmatrix} a& b& c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{pmatrix}  $$
Here what I'm seeing 
What is the work around for this issue?

This seems similar to: {, }, | and \ need an extra backslash to be rendered correctly in math when composing a new question in MSE. and MathJax preview works incorrectly in Google Chrome..

It seems that perhaps the main renderer and the question preview renderer are doing different things...


See this answer for a possible workaround.
